# Applying Seperate Rotations to Multiple Quads Using Old OpenGL Functionality

Tags: opengl

I want to render a quad with a certain rotation, additionally this quad has "leaf" quads rendered below it similar to a binary tree structure. Each of the children has their own rotation to be applied to them in addition to that of their parents. In other words, if the root quad rotates, the entire tree rotates with it but each sub-tree can rotate individually as well. So my recursive render function looks a little like this...

```
RenderNode(Node current_node){
    glRotate(current_node->rotation);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      // supply 4 vertices and texture mapping
    glEnd();

    RenderNode(current_node->leftChild);
    RenderNode(current_node->rightChild);
}
```

Now I would expect my child nodes to have slightly different rotations compared to their parents but unfortunately this is not the case. The more times glRotate() is called during a single frame the faster the rotation animation but all the plates stay on the same plane. It seems like none of the quads are being rendered until the very end and the latest transformation matrix is being applied to all of them. As a test I tried putting glPushMatrix() before each transformation and glPopMatrix() after each call to glEnd(), this completely stops the rotation of all of the plates.

Could someone enlighten me as to what's happening here?

Comment: Did you put `glIdentityMatrix()` before you you called `glPushMatrix()`?

Comment: No, just tried it and now the quads don't seem to render at all.

Comment: Sorry, `glLoadIdentity()` was the actual call...

Comment: Yea I figured that's what you meant, quads don't render at all with it.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of hackish because of the recursion, but this is the best base case I can come up with short notice:

Try this:

```
RenderNode(Node current_node, GLfloat parentRotation){
    if(current_node->leftChild != null) RenderNode(current_node->leftChild, parentRotation + current_node->rotation);
    if(current_node->rightChild != null) RenderNode(current_node->rightChild, parentRotation + current_node->rotation);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotate(current_node->rotation);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
      // supply 4 vertices and texture mapping
    glEnd();
}
```

This way you won't have to pop or push any matrices, it will just reset to the identity matrix for each actual geometry render. Just remember to call `glLoadIdentity()` again after rendering the mesh if you want to render anything else.

Comment: Well I want to have the parent transformations on the stack when rendering the children. For instance if the parent has an individual rotation of 45 and the child has an individual rotation of 3 then I actually want the child to be rotated by a total of 48 degrees. I can't get anything to render when I include a call to glLoadIdentity in the function.

Comment: Edited, why dont you just pass through a parent rotation float? Sum it as you go down the recursion tree, you may have to play around with the placement of the `glLoadIdentity` call